# Perl: `die` did not work upon opening a nonexistent gz file using gzip

Tags: perl, die

The following script creates a gziped file named "input.gz". Then the script attempts to open "input.gz" using `gzip -dc`. Intuitively, `die` should be triggered if a wrong input file name is provided. However, as in the following script, the program will not `die` even if a wrong input file name is provided ("inputx.gz"):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

system("echo PASS | gzip -c > input.gz");

open(IN,"-|","gzip -dc inputx.gz") || die "can't open input.gz!";

print STDOUT "die statment was not triggered!\n";

close IN;
```

The output of the script above was

```
die statment was not triggered!
gzip: inputx.gz: No such file or directory
```

**My questions** is: why wasn't `die` statement triggered even though `gzip` quit with error? And how can I make `die` statement triggered when a wrong file name is given?

Comment: `gzip` quit with an error, but `open` did not fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's buried in [perlipc](https://perldoc.pl/perlipc#Using-open%28%29-for-IPC), but this seems relevant (emphasis added):

> Be careful to check the return values from both open() and close(). If you're writing to a pipe, you should also trap SIGPIPE. Otherwise, think of what happens when you start up a pipe to a command that doesn't exist: **the open() will in all likelihood succeed (it only reflects the fork()'s success)**, but then your output will fail--spectacularly. Perl can't know whether the command worked, because your command is actually running in a separate process whose exec() might have failed. Therefore, while **readers of bogus commands return just a quick EOF**, writers to bogus commands will get hit with a signal, which they'd best be prepared to handle.

Use [`IO::Uncompress::Gunzip`](https://perldoc.pl/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip) to read gzipped files instead.

Answer (score 2):

The [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) documentation is explicit about `open`-ing a process since that is indeed different

> If you open a pipe on the command `-` (that is, specify either `|-` or `-|` with the one- or two-argument forms of `open`), an implicit `fork` is done, so `open` returns twice: in the parent process it returns the `pid` of the child process, and in the child process it returns (a defined) `0`. Use `defined($pid)` or `//` to determine whether the `open` was successful.
>
> For example, use either
>
> ```
> my $child_pid = open(my $from_kid, "-|") // die "Can't fork: $!";
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> my $child_pid = open(my $to_kid,   "|-") // die "Can't fork: $!";
> ```

(with code following that shows one use of this, which you don't need)   The main point is to check for `defined` -- by design we get `undef` if `open` for a process fails, not just any "false."

While this should be corrected, keep in mind that the `open` call fails *if `fork` itself fails*, what is rare; in most cases when a "command fails" the `fork` was successful but something later wasn't. So in such cases we just cannot get the `// die` message, but end up seeing messages from the shell or command or OS, hopefully.

This is alright though, if informative messages indeed get emitted by some part of the process. Wrap the whole thing in `eval` and you'll have manageable error reporting.

But it is in general difficult to ensure to get all the right messages, and in some cases not possible.  One good approach is to use a module for running and managing external commands. Among the many other advantages they also usually handle errors much more nicely. If you need to handle process's output right as it is emitted I recommend [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) (which i'd recommend otherwise as well).

Read on what linked docs say, for specific examples on what you need and for much useful insight.

---

In your case

```
# Check input, depending on how it is given,
# consider String::ShellQuote if needed
my $file = ...;

my @cmd = ('gzip', '-dc', $file);

my $child_pid = open my $in, '-|', @cmd  
    // die "Can't fork for '@cmd': $!";

while (<$in>) { 
    ...
}
close $in or die "Error closing pipe: $!";
```

Note a few other points

- the "list form" of the command bypasses the shell
- lexical filehandle (`my $fh`) is much better than typeglobs (`IN`)
- print the actual error in the `die` statement, in [`$!` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlvar.html#Error-Variables)
- check [close](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0//functions/close.html) for a good final check on how it all went